# Powershell: Move Files recursively

Tags: powershell, scripting, move

I am trying to copy all build output files and folders into a **Bin** folder (**OutputDir/Bin**) except of some files which stay in the **OutputDir**. The **Bin** folder will never be deleted.

**Initial condition:**

```
Output
   config.log4net
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
   file3.dll
   ProjectXXX.exe
   en
      foo.txt
   fr
      foo.txt
   de
      foo.txt
```

**Target:**

```
Output
   Bin
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      file3.dll
      en
         foo.txt
      fr
         foo.txt
      de
         foo.txt
   config.log4net
   ProjectXXX.exe
```

**My first try:**

```
$binaries = $args[0]
$binFolderName = "bin"
$binFolderPath = Join-Path $binaries $binFolderName

New-Item $binFolderPath -ItemType Directory

Get-Childitem -Path $binaries | ? {$_.Name -notlike "ProjectXXX.*" -and $_.Name -ne "config.log4net" -and $_.Name -ne $binFolderName }  | Move-Item -Destination $binFolderPath
```

This does not work, because `Move-Item` is not able to overwrite folders.

**My second try:**

```
function MoveItemsInDirectory {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][System.String]$SourceDirectoryPath,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)][System.String]$DestinationDirectoryPath,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)][System.Array]$ExcludeFiles)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirectoryPath -Exclude $ExcludeFiles | %{
        if ($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
            $newFilePath = Join-Path $DestinationDirectoryPath $_.Name
            xcopy $_.FullName $newFilePath /Y
            Remove-Item $_ -Force -Confirm:$false
        }
        else
        {
            $folderName = $_.Name
            $folderPath = Join-Path $DestinationDirectoryPath $folderName

            MoveItemsInDirectory -SourceDirectoryPath $_.FullName -DestinationDirectoryPath $folderPath -ExcludeFiles $ExcludeFiles
            Remove-Item $_ -Force -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}

$binaries = $args[0]
$binFolderName = "bin"
$binFolderPath = Join-Path $binaries $binFolderName
$excludeFiles = @("ProjectXXX.*", "config.log4net", $binFolderName)

MoveItemsInDirectory $binaries $binFolderPath $excludeFiles
```

Is there any alternative way of moving files recursively in a more easy way using PowerShell?

Comment: If you show an example folder structure of how it is and then how you want it to end up being it would help to get you the answer you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could replace the `Move-Item` command with an `Copy-Item` command and after that, you can delete the files you moved by simply calling `Remove-Item`:

```
$a = ls | ? {$_.Name -notlike "ProjectXXX.*" -and $_.Name -ne "config.log4net" -and $_.Name -ne $binFolderName }
$a | cp -Recurse -Destination bin -Force
rm $a -r -force -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Upvote for you, only downside is your filter only applies to items in the root, and doesn't apply the filter recursively.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, Move-Item will not overwrite folders so you're left with copying.  An alternative solution would be to call Robocopy for each file in your for-each loop with the /MOV switch (amongst others!); this will move then delete the source file.