# Moving files based on various criteria in Powershell 3.0

Tags: date, exception, powershell, recursion, powershell-3.0

I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?
[Powershell Move-Item Rename If File Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839787/powershell-move-item-rename-if-file-exists)
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/c347ce7a-3e23-4476-90c2-37b79785ac2f/moving-files-based-on-modified-date
[Powershell: Move Files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279706/powershell-move-files-recursively)
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/22/hey-scripting-guy-september-22-2009.aspx and about two dozen more articles.

I apologize, have little knowledge of scripting though I like learning it and the possibilities it provides. My previous positions didn't require me scripting other than the batch files using Windows CMD. I recently accepted a net admin position and my supervisor asked me to write a script that would move files based on several criteria. I'm using Powershell to accomplish this.

1. Files newer than one day be moved -not copied- from $path to $destination
2. Exclusion applies to callpilot.dev which must remain untouched
3. Files located in source folder as well as files located in all subfolders must be moved
4. The source folder structure must remain in place
5. Destination top folder must contain the actual date minus 1 day
6. All subfolder structure must be created using same names as source structure
7. Remaining source files should be deleted (except callpilot.dev)

Here's my test folder structure:

```
    c:\temp\others\callpilot 
    c:\temp\others\ftps 
    c:\temp\others\mysql 
    c:\temp\others\rss-enterprise 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8 
    c:\temp\others\tree.txt 
    c:\temp\others\callpilot\example2.gz 
    c:\temp\others\callpilot\backup.gz 
    c:\temp\others\callpilot\barnak.bak 
    c:\temp\others\callpilot\callpilot.dev 
    c:\temp\others\callpilot\IPESystemBackup 131022 2000.bkp 
    c:\temp\others\ftps\www.123.com 
    c:\temp\others\ftps\www.123.com\backup-10.22.2013_00-00-08_123.tar.gz 
    c:\temp\others\ftps\www.123.com\backup-10.23.2013_00-00-08_123.tar.gz 
    c:\temp\others\ftps\www.123.com\backup-10.4.2013_00-00-07_123.tar.gz 
    c:\temp\others\mysql\sql.txt 
    c:\temp\others\rss-enterprise\enterprise.txt 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8\data 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8\data\New Bitmap Image.bmp 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8\data\New Journal Document.jnt 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8\data\New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx 
    c:\temp\others\rss-sql2k8\data\New Microsoft Visio Drawing.vsd
```

Here's my script:

```
$date = get-date 
$path = "C:\temp\others\*.*"
$destination = new-item "c:\temp\others\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-"))" -type directory
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path -file -recurse -exclude "callpilot.dev")) 
{ 
    If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date) 
    { 
        Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $destination 
    } 
}
```

I'm missing the #6 and #7. Can you please help me finding them?

---

I got your reply thank you for that. Something is still not working right.

Here's my script:

```
$date = get-date
$path = "C:\temp\others\*.*"
$destination = new-item "c:\temp\others\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-"))" -type directory

Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path -file -recurse -exclude "callpilot.dev"))
{
    If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-2).date)
{
        $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root.ToString())
        New-Item $destination -Type Directory -ea SilentlyContinue
        Move-Item $file $destination
    } else {
        Remove-Item $file
}
}
```

The files moved but no folder were created. And the error is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:11 char:9
+         Move-Item $file $destination
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\temp\others\...sio Drawing.vsd:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\temp\organize_final222.ps1:9 char:9
+         $destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Did I insert your lines at the right place?

Comment: This sounds like a task better suited to Robocopy than PowerShell, or possibly a combination of the two.

Comment: I thought that too at the beginning but I need the "real move" which involves changing folder pointers as opposed to what **Robocopy** does, "copy then delete source". What does it do that **Powershell** can't do? Also, I'm curious as to how to integrate Robocopy in a Powershell script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root.ToString())` to get the source folderpath without the drive name, so this will take care of #6:

```
$destination += '\' + $file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root.ToString())
New-Item $destination -Type Directory -ea SilentlyContinue
Move-Item $file $destination
```

A few notes:

- The first line appends the original path (excluding the drive letter) to **$destination**.
- The second line creates the destination directory, if it doesn't exist. `-ea SilentlyContinue` prevents it from complaining if the destination directory already exists. You could be anal and do `if (! (Test-Path $destination)) {New-Item ...`, but I think that's a waste of time.
- You can leave out the parameter names **-Path** and **-Destination** because they're implied by the position (Google "powershell positional parameters" for more info).
- You don't need to read the **FullName** property. If you provide a non-string argument to a string paramater, PowerShell automatically invokes the **ToString()** method on the argument. So, `Move-Item $file $dest` is the same as `Move-Item $file.ToString() $dest`, and invoking the **ToString()** method on a FileInfo object gives you the **FullName** property (this is specified by the object class definition). This may seem like a minor point, but you'll find yourself doing a lot less unnecessary typing once you get used to it. The general rule is that if it intuitively seems like it should work, it probably will (as in, it's intuitive that you should be able to just tell it to move a file object without doing any fancy stuff like specifying a property of the object -- so you can.)

For #7, simply add an **else** clause to delete source files that don't match the condition:

```
if ($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date) {
  Move-Item $file "$destination\$($file.DirectoryName.TrimStart($file.Directory.Root.ToString()))"
} else {
  Remove-Item $file
}
```

To be on the safe side, I'd recommend doing a test run with `Remove-Item -WhatIf $file` to make sure you're getting the results you want. Even better would be to declare `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]` at the beginning of the script and run the whole script with **-WhatIf**, but that's probably more advanced than you want to get right now. The important part is to always do a non-destructive test run before letting a script make a large number of irreversible changes.